# How to insert one latex document into another.

Tags: input, include, document-configuration

This is probably online but I am not sure how to word the search. I have a long `latex` document, and it is getting messy editing it, is there a way to split the chapters into separate `latex` documents and insert like a reference to them in the main document  such that when the main document is build they will show in the pdf.

Thanks.

Comment: @duffymo thanks `\include` was what I was looking for.

Comment: Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: See also [When should I use \input vs. \include?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/2975)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `\input{firstfile}`

see http://web.science.mq.edu.au/~rdale/resources/writingnotes/latexstruct.html for more information.

Comment: Altin Thanks for the answer `\include{firstfile}` was what I was looking for.